# Examples of using MCMC for GP regression

Tags: bayesian, references, markov-chain-montecarlo, gaussian-process, nonparametric-regression

This is a reference request. I am in a position of needing to use MCMC to do Gaussian process regression for a project. I have used MCMC before, and I have used GPs before, but never together. It would be very helpful to me to walk through some examples. Best of all would be to have one or more extremely simple examples in addition to some more complex examples; in both cases, the more hand-holding the better.

Comment: Could you tell more about your use case? Are tools like Stan or PyMC3 things you want to use? Or do want you get your hands dirty?

Comment: @Pieter I'd prefer to get my hands dirty with coding it directly either in R, MATLAB or (if necessary) Python. In the problem I'm working with, it's 2D output; we're putting priors on most of the covariance parameters and the mean of the GP but we're plugging in MLEs for a couple of the covariance parameters. We've got like 60 data points, which are from a computationally expensive FE model we're trying to emulate with a GP.